# Nixie Clock PCB design review

Tags: nixie

this is my second pcb design and the first one that works. Looking to get a review.

This is nixie clock driver for IN-14 tubes on К155ИД1, arduino IoT and [170V dc-dc booster](https://omnixie.io/assets/products/nch8200hv/nch8200hv_datasheet_en_v2.0.0.pdf)

[image: schematic]

[image: pcb]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, but if it works what are we looking for? There are no part numbers on any of the devices on the schematic except the Arduino Uno. I think you'd need to fix that first before anyone could help.

Comment: There look to be a lot of shorts. Does this exact PCB actually work?

Comment: It seems strange for the part numbers to be on the PCB silkscreen, but not the schematic.

Comment: If you want a review, you should have some specs or explanation how the circuitry is supposed to work. So we can say if it works like you expect or not. Right now, we have no idea if it fills any requirements you have. Most likely not with those parts you use. The PCB may work, but the schematics may not.

Comment: The 10 outputs of the driver chip IC74141 Q0 .. Q9 should go directly to the 10 cathodes of the Nixie tubes. Your schematic, however, shows inexplicable interconnections between these. For example, IC2 output Q1 appears to be shorted to Q8 and and these in turn are connected to J2 (cathode) pins 2 and 3. See something like: https://en.kohacraft.com/archives/until-the-k155id1-is-controlled-by-the-esp-32-and-the-2-digit-nixie-tube-in-12b-is-dynamically-lit.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't design PCBs professionally and haven't created one for many years but here are some comments.

1. Putting part numbers on the silk screen is not usually done as it means that the PCB will be "wrong" if a part substitution is done during production.

[image]

*Figure 1. Inadequate clearance between traces and between pads and traces highlighted in yellow.*

2. Inadequate clearance between traces. In the screen grab many of the red traces seem to be connected or overlapping.
3. Inadequate clearance between traces and pads.
4. Uneven spacing between traces and pads. Most of the traces running between pads are off-centre. Normal practice for a 0.1" grid would be to run them down the 0.05" grid line exactly centred between the pads to maximise clearance on both sides evenly.
5. Two traces running between pads. See the top left connector where two red traces run between the second and third pads when there is an alternate route the other side of the third pad.
6. Connector designators missing on silk screen.
7. Pin 1 identificion or orientation symbol missing on all connectors and the Uno. Common practice would also be to make pin 1 a square pad to aid in debugging the rear of the board.

[image]

*Figure 2. Strange goings-on with vias?*

8. The white dots in Figure 2 seem to be vias. It's unclear why multiple vias are required on each track and why the rightmost track drops to the underside of the board, back up to the top and then down again.

[image]

*Figure 3. Short circuit around component?*

9. Figure 3 shows what appears to be a red trace outline outside of a square component (with no component designator). This trace is short-circuiting the other traces connected to the device.

[image]

*Figure 4. Lower edge of board.*

10. Figure 4 shows traces running unnecessarily close to pads again. Also running the trace right along the edge of the board risks damage and narrowing of the trace during board cutting.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for detailed review. My bad I used low quality image export settings in eagle. traces don't touch and board is working. I was wondering if it is safe to run it without a fuse? Do I need any capacitors or diodes? I would assume arduino has some protection circuits built in.